# protoc-gen-grpc The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2019, grpc, grpc-c#

Hi I'm tring to build a C# program which uses protobuf. When I do it on my computer everything is fine. But I copied the project to another computer and try to rebuild the program and that error comes out.

```
protoc-gen-grpc The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I'm using VisualStudio 2019 and on indication about where or what line causes the problem. There are countless lins of code so I don't know what to show. I've serched the google but usually finds answers for this error

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

or

```
protoc-gen-grpc: The system cannot find the file specified
```

this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing.

> **TL;DR** `protoc-gen-grpc` is a plugin for the `protoc` compiler that enables it to generate gRPC sources for one of the supported languages e.g. C#

The compiler (`protoc`) converts protocol buffers files to language-specific sources. gRPC extends protocol buffers. In order to generate source code from gRPC protos you often need 2 plugins for each language. One to generate the proto messages and another (in your case `protoc-gen-grpc`) to compile the services/rpcs.

C# is additionally confusing because you've .NET Framework and .NET Core and, it appears, there's a new implementation.

I recommend you view the [gRPC for .NET](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/dotnet/) content on [gRPC](https://grpc.io) and [The future of gRPC in C# belongs to grpc-dotnet](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-csharp-future/)